# Convert a Single Dimension Array to Two Dimensional Array with DAG Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, directed-acyclic-graphs

We are building an application where the client will be able to build a workflow, represented as a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). When output on the screen it will look like this:

[image: DAG workflow display]

The above graph is output to the screen using a two dimensional array, and the model looks like this:

```js
const dag = [
  [
    { id: 1, parentId: 0 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
    { id: 3, parentId: 1 }
  ],
  [
    { id: 6, parentId: 2 },
    { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
    { id: 5, parentId: 3 }
  ],
]
```

The two dimensional array model allows me to loop over it and output each row on the screen; so the first item in the `dag` model is the first row with one node, the second item in the `dag` model is the second row with two nodes, and so on.

That part works, and I even have figured out how to dynamically add nodes to the graph on the fly. The part I'm running into issues with is creating the two dimensional array from a single dimensional array. The data for the graph will go to the server and be returned from the server as a single dimensional array, like this:

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 0 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 2 },
]
```

I need to take this `items` array and convert it into the `dag` multidimensional array above.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
// this is the end array, (two dimensions [][]), that will be used to draw the graph
const dag = [];

// this will create the first row of the array, with all the items that have a parentId of 0
const newRow = items
  .filter((item) => item.parentId === 0)
  .reduce((arr, item) => {
    arr.push(item);
    return arr;
  }, []);
dag.push(newRow);

// Now I'm trying to move down the graph from top to bottom
dag.forEach((row) => {
  // get the list of item IDs that are in this row
  const itemIdsInRow = row.reduce((prev, row) => {
    prev.push(row.id);
    return prev;
  }, []);

  // use the itemIdsInRow to get the items from the single dimensional array that will go in the next row
  const itemsForNextRow = itemIdsInRow.reduce((itemsArr, id) => {
    const nextItems = items.filter((item) => item.parentId === id);
    itemsArr.push(...nextItems);
    return itemsArr;
  }, []);

  // push the new row onto the two dimension array
  dag.push(itemsForNextRow);
});
```

This works for the first two rows of the `dag`. It makes sense; as I push on to the `dag` model, the `forEach` doesn't let me continue going through the loop to build the third row. If I start the `dag` array before the `forEach` with the first two rows, I can build the third row correctly, so the algorithm to build the `dag` is pretty close to being there.

If you have any input or ideas on how to solve this I'd be really grateful. Thanks!

### Edit

We also have a need now for each item's `parentId` to be an array of `parentId`s. This is because two branches can be combined back at a point, so a node may have two (or more) parents. Imagine in the above picture that nodes 4 and 5 have a child node below them that each of them connect to. Here is the starting array and the result array in code:

```js
const start = [
  { isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 1', parentIds: [0], stepId: 1, type: DagBranchType.Normal },
  { isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 2', parentIds: [1], stepId: 2, type: DagBranchType.IfElse },
  { isYesPath: true, name: 'Step 3', parentIds: [2], stepId: 3, type: DagBranchType.Normal },
  { isYesPath: false, name: 'Step 4', parentIds: [2], stepId: 4, type: DagBranchType.Normal },
  { isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 5', parentIds: [3, 4], stepId: 5, type: DagBranchType.Normal },
]

const result = [
  [{ isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 1', parentIds: [0], stepId: 1, type: DagBranchType.Normal }],
  [{ isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 2', parentIds: [1], stepId: 2, type: DagBranchType.IfElse }],
  [
    { isYesPath: true, name: 'Step 3', parentIds: [2], stepId: 3, type: DagBranchType.Normal },
    { isYesPath: false, name: 'Step 4', parentIds: [2], stepId: 4, type: DagBranchType.Normal }
  ],
  [{ isYesPath: undefined, name: 'Step 5', parentIds: [3, 4], stepId: 5, type: DagBranchType.Normal }]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get desired result by using `forEach` and `filter` methods to create one recursive function and pass down parent id and current level. You can then use level to add to the result array by index.

```js
const items = [{"id":1,"parentId":0},{"id":2,"parentId":1},{"id":3,"parentId":1},{"id":4,"parentId":3},{"id":5,"parentId":3},{"id":6,"parentId":2}]

const result = []

const modify = (data, pid = 0, level = 0) => data
  .filter(({ parentId }) => parentId === pid)
  .forEach(e => {
    if (!result[level]) result[level] = [e]
    else result[level].push(e);

    modify(data, e.id, level + 1)
  })


modify(items)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: do you know how to get this same result, but with parentId being an array of parentIds instead of a single parentId? So for example the item with ID of 5, could have as its parentIds 3 and 4? I tried altering the function but it adds multiple copies of item 5 to the final array.

Comment: @pjlamb12 What would be desired result in that case?

Comment: It's essentially the opposite of one node branching into two separate nodes. The idea is that two nodes, i.e. node 3 and node 4, could combine back with node 5. So node 5 has two parents.

Comment: Could you post desired result data for that case maybe in your question or in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I just added an edit to the original question with more details. It has a starting array of items and what the result should look like.

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/w8o3v6f2/

Answer (score 1):

There are already couple of solutions however, I would like to suggest one without mutations.

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 0 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 2 },
];

const partition = predicate => list => [
  list.filter (predicate),
  list.filter (x => !predicate (x)),
];

const inLevel = nth => original => item => {
  if (nth < 0) return false;
  const parent = original.find (({id}) => id === item.parentId);
  return !parent ? nth === 0 : inLevel (nth - 1) (original) (parent);
};

const buildTree = (original) => (list, nth = 0) => {
  const [currentLevel, rest] = partition (inLevel (nth) (original)) (list);
  return rest.length > 0
    ? [ currentLevel, ...buildTree (original) (rest, nth + 1) ]
    : [ currentLevel ];
}

console.log (buildTree (items) (items));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, or most efficient, but it does work. Basically I keep track of which of objects from the `items` array have been used, and when they have I push them on to the `usedItems` array. I loop over the code that adds new rows to the `dag` model while `usedItems.length !== items.length`.

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, parentId: 0 },
  { id: 2, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 3, parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 5, parentId: 3 },
  { id: 6, parentId: 2 },
];
// As items are used, push them on this array
const usedItems = [];

// this is the end array, (two dimensions [][]), that will be used to draw the graph
const dag = [];

// this will create the first row of the array, with all the items that have a parentId of 0
const newRow = items
  .filter((item) => item.parentId === 0)
  .reduce((arr, item) => {
    arr.push(item);
    return arr;
  }, []);
dag.push(newRow);
usedItems.push(...newRow);

// go until the usedItems array is the same length as the original items array
while (usedItems.length !== items.length) {
  // get the list of item IDs that are in this row
  const row = dag[dag.length - 1];
  const itemIdsInRow = row.reduce((prev, row) => {
    prev.push(row.id);
    return prev;
  }, []);

  // use the itemIdsInRow to get the items from the single dimensional array that will go in the next row
  const itemsForNextRow = itemIdsInRow.reduce((itemsArr, id) => {
    const nextItems = items.filter((item) => item.parentId === id);
    itemsArr.push(...nextItems);
    return itemsArr;
  }, []);

  // push the new row onto the two dimension array
  dag.push(itemsForNextRow);
  usedItems.push(...itemsForNextRow);
}
```